# Are "fault" and "default" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology

*Fault* and *default* sound rather similar to me as a German, but are they really related?

I am interested in *default* as used in *default value* for some configurable setting in computer programs.

Comment: It was always fun training Realtors in software: the word 'default' made their hair stand on end. "No, it's a *Good Thing*."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Fault](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fault)

> late 13c., faute,
> "deficiency," from O.Fr. faute (12c.)
> "opening, gap;  failure, flaw, blemish; lack, deficiency," from V.L. ***fallita**
> "a shortcoming, falling," noun use of fem. pp., from L. falsus
> "deceptive, feigned, spurious," pp. of **fallere**
> "deceive, disappoint" (see false).
>
> The -l- was restored 16c., probably in imitation of Latin, but was not pronounced till 18c.
>
> Sense of "physical defect" is from early 14c.;
> that of "moral culpability" is first recorded late 14c.
> Geological sense is from 1796.
> The use in tennis (c.1600) is closer to the etymological sense.

### [Default](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=default)

> early 13c., "offense, crime, sin," later (late 13c.) "failure, failure to
> act," from O.Fr. defaute (12c.)
> "fault, defect, failure, culpability, lack, privation," from V.L. *de**fallita**
> "a deficiency or failure," pp. of *defallere, from L. de- "away" (see de-) + **fallere**
> "to deceive, to cheat;  to put wrong, to lead astray, cause to be mistaken; to escape notice of, be concealed from" (see fail).
> The financial sense is first recorded 1858; the computing sense is from 1966.

Wikipedia says

> The Oxford English Dictionary dates
> this usage to the mid-1960s, as a
> variant of the older meaning of "failure in performance".

[bold is mine]

Comment: The bit that is missing is the derivation of the computer sense. I believe it arises from the phrase "in default of" (eg "in default of payment"), interpreting that as simply "if lacking" rather than "if wrong". But I haven't any references for that.

Comment: @Colin Thanks for the heads-up, I hadn't noticed the edit to the question

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are related.

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/), [fault](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fault) traces its ancestry back through the Old French *faute* to the Latin *fallere*, "to deceive".  Similarly [default](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=default) traces back through the Old French *defaute* to the Latin *defallere*, which is just *de-* ("away from" or "out of") + *fallere*.

"Default" in the computing sense straightforwardly derives as the value chosen "by default", or "in default of" an explicit value.  In both of those phrases "default" is used to mean a lack or omission, part of its ordinary definition.

Answer (score -2):

The logic behind the use of "default value" in software is a bit twisted. It is based on the programmer looking at the user's actions entirely from computer's point of view. For example, by pressing Ctrl-P to print a file, you point out the file and the action, but leave out plenty of other information the computer needs to carry out your request to print a file. To fill in the missing data, the computer uses “default values” as a way to "de-fault" your omission, so to say.

In other words, in a programmers' world-view, the user is always at fault.

Comment: Without any sources to back up these claims, this looks like urban etymology and as such does not provide a useful answer to the question.

Comment: I wanted to add the text as comment to an already existing posting, but didn't have enough points yet. I admit I used a bit too colourful language, but the basic logic still holds.